# PHP PDO fetchAll() on bool

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop, pdo

i try to write my own PDO wrapper-class, my statements always return `true` and I can't fetch anything.

Here is my `DB` class

```
class DB {

private $db;
private $host = "localhost";
private $database = "test";
private $user = "test";
private $password ="test";

public function __construct(){
    try {
        $this->db = new \PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->database, $this->user, $this->password);
        $this->db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (\PDOException $error) {
        die("Verbindung zur Datenbank fehlgeschlagen: <br>" . $error);
    }
}

public function run($sql, $args = []){
    try{
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stmt->execute($args);
        return $result;
    } catch(\PDOException $error) {
        die("Fehler bei Datenbankabfrage: <br>". $error);
    }
}
}
```

And here I instantiate a new instance of my class and try to fetch data

```
$DB = new DB();
$data = $DB->run("SELECT * FROM testtbl")->fetchAll();
```

Without the `fetchAll()` it returns true and with it throws an error in my error.log

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean

It would be nice if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) just returns a boolean which says whether the query succeeded or not. You need to call [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) on the statement, so instead of

```
return $result;
```

you should have

```
return $stmt;
```